# CentOS6 box: yum remove Percona-Server-shared-51 dependencies

Tags: centos, centos6, yum, percona

I want to install Percona 5.7, but when I run the relevant yum command it tells me that 57 clashes with Percona-Server-shared-51.  I don't really know why I even have that installed, since I also have Percona-Server-shared-56.

```
rpm -qa | grep Percona

Percona-Server-client-56-5.6.30-rel76.3.el6.x86_64
Percona-Server-shared-51-5.1.73-rel14.12.625.rhel6.x86_64
Percona-Server-shared-56-5.6.30-rel76.3.el6.x86_64
Percona-Server-server-56-5.6.30-rel76.3.el6.x86_64
```

I can uninstall the 56 versions trivially, but still run into the same clash with 51.

When I try to remove that, I come up against this:

```
yum remove Percona-Server-shared-51

Removing:
 Percona-Server-shared-51                 x86_64                 5.1.73-rel14.12.625.rhel6                   @percona-release-x86_64                                  5.9 M
Removing for dependencies:
 cronie                                   x86_64                 1.4.4-15.el6_7.1                            @updates                                                 174 k
 cronie-anacron                           x86_64                 1.4.4-15.el6_7.1                            @updates                                                  43 k
 crontabs                                 noarch                 1.10-33.el6                                 @anaconda-CentOS-201311291202.x86_64/6.5                 2.4 k
 munin                                    noarch                 2.0.25-11.el6                               @epel                                                    535 k
 munin-node                               noarch                 2.0.25-11.el6                               @epel                                                    1.3 M
 postfix                                  x86_64                 2:2.6.6-6.el6_7.1                           @updates                                                 9.7 M
 sysstat                                  x86_64                 9.0.4-31.el6                                @base                                                    826 k
 yum-cron                                 noarch                 3.2.29-73.el6.centos                        @base                                                     28 k
```

Am I ok to continue, and then just reinstall those packages once I've installed Percona 5.7, or will I run into problems?  Will I lose any config that those packages are currently set up with, etc?

Thanks!

If I uninstall all the 56 packages, and then try to install 57 server/client (NOT shared), I get this output:

```
yum install Percona-Server-server-57 Percona-Server-client-57

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                                                                        |  17 kB     00:00
 * base: centos.mirror.fr.planethoster.net
 * epel: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * extras: centos.quelquesmots.fr
 * ius: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * remi-safe: rpms.remirepo.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.fr.planethoster.net
base                                                                                                                                                 | 3.7 kB     00:00
epel                                                                                                                                                 | 4.3 kB     00:00
extras                                                                                                                                               | 3.4 kB     00:00
ius                                                                                                                                                  | 2.2 kB     00:00
nginx                                                                                                                                                | 2.9 kB     00:00
percona-release-noarch                                                                                                                               | 2.5 kB     00:00
percona-release-x86_64                                                                                                                               | 2.5 kB     00:00
remi-safe                                                                                                                                            | 2.9 kB     00:00
updates                                                                                                                                              | 3.4 kB     00:00
varnish-4.1                                                                                                                                          |  951 B     00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package Percona-Server-client-57.x86_64 0:5.7.12-5.1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: Percona-Server-shared-57 for package: Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.12-5.1.el6.x86_64
---> Package Percona-Server-server-57.x86_64 0:5.7.12-5.1.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package Percona-Server-shared-57.x86_64 0:5.7.12-5.1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: Percona-Server-shared-51-5.1.73-rel14.12.625.rhel6.x86_64 conflicts mysql-libs
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Percona-Server-shared-51 conflicts with Percona-Server-shared-57-5.7.12-5.1.el6.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
Percona-Server-shared-51-5.1.73-rel14.12.625.rhel6.x86_64 has installed conflicts mysql-libs: Percona-Server-shared-51-5.1.73-rel14.12.625.rhel6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep Percona-Server-shared-51. The rest can be uninstalled.

You just need to:

```
yum remove Percona-Server-client-56-\* Percona-Server-shared-56-\* Percona-Server-server-56-\*
yum install Percona-Server-server-57 Percona-Server-client-57
```

You can see the dependencies with:

```
sudo yum deplist postfix|egrep -i "mysql|percona"
```

Comment: Thanks Mircea, that didn't work unfortunately - see the edit to the original question.

Comment: try to remove with `rpm -qa | grep Percona-Server-shared | xargs rpm -e --nodeps` install 5.7 packages then install Percona Server shared compat 51 or whatever is needed as dependency. Install percona-xtrabackup-24 as well while you're at it.

Comment: It is not recommended to use `rpm` to install or uninstall packages. You should use `yum` or `dnf`.

Comment: You must see what are dependencies for postfix, crontab, etc. After that you can install and uninstall packages with `yum shell` in a single transaction. Worst case, you can uninstall postfix, crontab and the rest and install them later. Uninstalling them will not remove the config, however I always recommend to use `etckeeper` to keep the  configs in a source control repository (e.g. `git`). But use this approach as a last resort.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest percona yum repository. See: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.7/installation/yum_repo.html#installing-percona-server-from-percona-yum-repository

Comment: `You should keep Percona-Server-shared-51` doesn't make sense, why keep shared-51 when Percona provides shared-57?

Comment: I think `Percona-Server-shared-51` was required by `postfix` or some other programs that are using MySQL libraries. I do not recall the details.